# How do I install Intel HD graphics Skylake driver?

Tags: graphic-drivers

I just bought a laptop with I7 6500u and integrated GPU. It won't run 3D game at all. I tried the Intel graphics installer for linux but it said I don't use i915 chipset.

How do I update the driver properly?

Here is some information if needed:

```
hai@hai-Lenovo-ideapad-300-14ISK:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3808]
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
hai@hai-Lenovo-ideapad-300-14ISK:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
hai@hai-Lenovo-ideapad-300-14ISK:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I am told that Skylake is supported in kernel versions 4.3 and upwards.

Have you upgraded the kernel ?

Comment: yes. to 4.4 and the mouse became invisible. Game won/t run

Comment: Support for Skylake is poor at the moment. Elementary OS Freya  is based on Ubuntu 14.04, according to this article http://dstromberg.com/2015/12/skylake-graphics-on-linux-mint-and-ubuntu/   Ubuntu 15.04 is recommended, you may have better luck with Elementary OS loki, but if you have the 3D working with 4.4 then it may be easier to fix the mouse issue.

Comment: 3d still not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running ElementaryOS 0.4 Loki you should do two things:

1. Update Kernel to latest LTS HWE stack:

   > sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
2. Install newest Mesa 3D drivers from Padoka Stable PPA:

   > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa && sudo apt update

Hope this helps.